# Need to create a static instance of a complex object whose state I can determine at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I am using the Orchard CMS Module "File Manager" but this module has a glaring bug: it only updates its data tables when turned on/off.

I have pinpointed the section of code that needs to run and I know where this code needs to be called, but the object whose member function is being called has too many member objects to log its state by hand.

The solutions I have come up with are:

1. Create a static object with the same properties as the runtime version (which may not work due to it needing active connections dependent on the application state)
2. Recreate a copy of this object at runtime with minimal use of parameters etc.

I don't know if there is a better way to do this or if either of the above strategies will even work.  How can I do this within the .NET framework or within the context of Orchard CMS?

Comment: If you have found a bug, you should file it against that module. Also, avoid static, as you will only create new problems. I think what you are looking for is caching, and there are existing APIs for that.

Comment: Sounds a bit cryptic to me. Could you please paste the code you're referring to and describe in more details what you want to achieve? Why static?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I had been OOO.  I wanted the static instance to replicate the program state when the images are added.  It would exist solely to be called every time the user imports media files.